# Is noise necessary so as to have music?

Tags: logic

Granted the following assumptions:

1. Music can be thought of as a string of sounds.
2. Noise can also be thought of as a string of sounds.
3. Every sequence of sounds can be considered music.

Would the following conclusions follow?

1. There would be at least one noise.
2. Every sequence of sounds is noise.

Comment: Everything that can be digitized is a bitstring. I was thinking that music is non-random and noise is random in the sense of Kolmogorov complexity. But that's not right. 01010101... is nonrandom, but it's not music either. So music (and art in general) is characterized by a high degree of order at some levels; and just the right amount of randomness at others. I think this is a difficult question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: Assuming 'Sound': audible pressure wave; 'Noise': collection or sequence of sounds; 'Music': collection or sequence of sounds that meets some aesthetic criteria, then: Yes, all music is noise but not all noise is music.  Similarly, all squares are rectangles (but not all rectangles are squares) and all whales are mammals (but not all mammals are whales).  But as mentioned, these answers hinge on the definitions of the terms in question.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with logic. But note that [John Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cage) in 1952 "composed the piece that became his best-known and most controversial creation: *4′33″*. The score instructs the performer not to play the instrument during the entire duration of the piece—four minutes, thirty-three seconds—and is meant to be perceived as consisting of the sounds of the environment that the listeners hear while it is performed."

Comment: @user4894 I've edited the question to make the fallacy apparent. Feel free to edit it if I've distorted the meaning you intended to convey.

Comment: @stoicfury The problem, which I have tried to emphasize with my edit, is that there is a basic logical fallacy there, regardless of the possible definitions of 'music' and 'noise' and 'sound'. I too would like clarity about the meanings of those notions, but for a start, I think it would be a good idea to address the obvious fallacy. (The fallacy, which I'm sure you've noticed, is that from premises 1) Mx → Sx, 2) Nx → Sx, 3) Sx → Mx; Mx ↔ Sx follows, but 2) Sx → Nx and 1) ∃x: Nx do not.)

Comment: @HunanRostomyan Thanks for the edit, and I understand, but — at least from a moderation perspective — questions are not required to be fallacy-free, they just need to be focused enough to have a single real answer and not generate extended discussion. :) I think this is good enough now to be reopened as a question about logic. #Mauro - 'Logic' appears to be the tag the OP used for this question, so apparently at least s/he thinks it's a question about logic.

Answer (score 1):

Not my area of expertise, but the basic problem hinges on a confusion in the use of "noise."  This could be a result of language or just word choice.

but what you need is three terms: "music", "noise", and "sound." Sound would refer to the medium. Music to a "logical" arrangement of sounds. Noise would then be the "illogical" arrangement of sounds. By logical, I mean ordered according to some system -- which need not be identical for all listeners and composers but still needs to be some system.

Thus, on these definitions, music is no more sound than yes is no or true is false. Both involve sound in the same way speaking a language and grinding your fingernails against a chalkboard involve sound, but they differ precisely.

Comment: Is John Cage's 4'33" music? This is a real corner case! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%B233%E2%80%B3

Comment: For the purposes of the answer, yes. Silence is an arrangement of sound. For the purposes of taste, no.

Comment: You did not notice that noise also has system. Perhaps more mathematical/logical than music.

Comment: @user4894: it's worth observing that 4'33" involves a lack of intentional instrumentation, but it is not therefore a lack of *sound* as such. As the article you linked says "Cage had gone to a place where he expected total silence, and yet heard sound."

Comment: @AsphirDom you seem to be confused about the definition of noise.

Comment: @virmaior Please read about White noise. Understand that any noise is a physical process and as such is very well predicted. Rethink. Give music some credit as to being unlogical.ty

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the liberty of editing the original question to reflect what, after multiple readings, I took to be OP's main question. The idea is to begin with a couple of reasonable assumptions (premises 1–3), presented at a very general level (not digging too deep into the possible interpretations of the words 'music', 'sound', 'noise', or the representability of music via sequences of sounds, etc), and then to consider the plausibility, given those assumptions, of conclusions (1—2).

The edit should make the problem apparent, but I'll take the opportunity to describe what it is exactly. The problem is a logical one, so let's look at the logical structure of the premises:

P1. ∀<sub>x</sub> : Music(x) → SoundSequence(x),
   P2. ∀<sub>x</sub> : Noise(x) → SoundSequence(x),
   P3. ∀<sub>x</sub> : SoundSequence(x) → Music(x);

and that of the conclusions:

C1. ∃<sub>x</sub> : SoundSequence(x) ∧ Noise(x),
   C2. ∀<sub>x</sub> : SoundSequence(x) → Noise(x).

The three premises seem reasonable: (P1) every piece of music is a sequence of sounds, (P2) the same goes for noise, and (P3) any sequence of sounds is music. This third assumption is rather controversial, but we're interested in logical consequence rather than the truth of particular assumptions. Granted those assumptions, do conclusions (C1) and (C2) follow? The first says that there is some sequence of sounds that is noise; the second says that *all* sound sequences are noise.

Neither conclusion follows, of course. From purely universal premises no existential conclusion could ever be expected. For any empty universe satisfies them, but won't satisfy *any* existential conclusions. But even if the existence of a sound sequence followed from the premises by some additional assumption, there is no reason to conclude that that sequence of sounds would be noise. Now, conclusion (C2) says exactly that: all sequences of sound are noise. It doesn't follow from the premises, but what if we added it to the premises? Here is what we would get:

(P1 ∧ P3) ∀<sub>x</sub> : Music(x) ↔ SoundSequence(x),
   (P2 ∧ P4) ∀<sub>x</sub> : Noise(x) ↔ SoundSequence(x),

where the new premise (P4) is the old conclusion (C2). Conclusion (C1), now simply the conclusion, would still not follow because of the existential import problem mentioned above. We would need a fifth premise to the effect that there exists a sequence of sounds. If that were granted, then the conclusion would follow, but a lot would still be left to desire as regards the soundness of the argument, given the very strong assumption (P4 ≡ C2), which, by the way, also renders the following conclusion valid:

∀<sub>x</sub> : Music(x) ↔ Noise(x).

<sub>This post should have been a lot shorter, for the point is simple. I'll try to compress it soon.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes.

One can believe music is simply a sequence of sounds that stands out from the noise, if for no other reason than that it is different and does not reflect any underlying order. Or one can believe music reflects an underlying order and we can detect this reflection and identify it as such.

In both cases, one an assignment of relative value, and the other an assignment of absolute value, a point of reference is needed. Points of reference are obviously needed for relative judgments. For absolute judgments references are also needed, because if we lived in a quintessential world everything would be perfect and nothing would change, and thus judgment of anything would be nonsensical.